# Django import csv HTML

Tags: python, django, csv

hi im currently try to import a csv file into a django project with out using the django admin. the code ive written seems to work when in python run but im unsure about how to build the html template as i cant seem to find any examples. Is anyone able to either post an example or point me in the right direction

my code is

Forms

```
class DataInput(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()


def save(self):
    records = csv.reader(self.cleaned_data["file"])
    for line in records:
        parts = Part()
        parts.supplier_id = line[0]
        parts.name = line[1]
        parts.description = line[2]
        parts.save()
```

view

```
def csv_import(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DataInput(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            success = True
            context = {"form": form, "success": success}
            return render_to_response("imported.html", context,
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = DataInput()
        context = {"form": form}
        return render_to_response("imported.html", context,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

thanks in advance

Comment: It's unclear what you're wanting to accomplish.  Example of what?  Is the code giving you an error?

Comment: sorry the code seems to be working fine but i cant seem to get any HTML templates to allow the csv to be uploaded ill add it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your upload template will look something like this if you just want to use the default form rendering:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    ...

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action=".">
        {{ form }}
    </form>

    ...
</html>
```

The distinguishing part is the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` that [lets it handle the file upload field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files).